# After I install program with wine, I can't launch it due to missing dll's. How do I add them?

Tags: wine

i can't install any program with wine on ubuntu 12.04.
For example i can't install zune ( windowsphone sync ) on ubuntu 12.04.
when Installing ( zune program ) i Take this Error :
" wine program crash
internal errors - invalid parameters received "

please help me.

basamraz@live.com

tanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wine website](http://winehq.org):

> There are of course DLLs that Wine does not currently implement very
>   well (or at all).
>
> In case Wine complains about a missing DLL, you should check whether
>   this file is a publicly available DLL or a custom DLL belonging to
>   your program. In the latter case, check that you have installed your
>   program correctly.
>
> Most often applications will assume that a required redistributable
>   package has already been installed and subsequently fail to run when
>   the required dependencies are not met. For example:
>
> err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by
>   L"C:\Program Files\Foo\Bar.dll") not found
>
> Redistributable packages which install the necessary runtimes can be
>   obtained through the use of winetricks. Note, these components are
>   subject to their own license and are not part of the Wine project. You
>   should refer to the application's AppDB entry for advice on what is
>   required.